# jQuery.submit is deprecated as of 3.3 what's the alternative?

Tags: jquery

By checking the source you can see:

```
/**
 * Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.
 *
 * @param handler A function to execute each time the event is triggered.
 * @see {@link https://api.jquery.com/submit/}
 * @since 1.0
 * @deprecated 3.3
 */
```

However it seems this isn't mentioned in the jQuery blog [here](https://blog.jquery.com/2018/01/19/jquery-3-3-0-a-fragrant-bouquet-of-deprecations-and-is-that-a-new-feature/). What is the alternative for this that it's now being marked deprecated?

Comment: No, it's not deprecated!

Comment: Deprecated = Not current.  Obsolete = no longer available.  IMHO the reason is because as browsers/html standards add more events, the team doesn't want to keep adding aliases when `.on()` does the same exact thing.

Comment: It is mentioned in the blog, twice. "Move event aliases to deprecated."

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize it since I was looking for submit on the page, not the broader `event aliases`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `.on`

```
$(selector).on("submit", callback)
```

Read more about it at http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 22):

I was also searching for this but in my case I wanted to trigger submit. In that case you do it by triggering the event:

```
$(selector).trigger("submit")
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't deprecated, you can check here the `.submit()` API docs:

https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Deprecated = Not current. Obsolete = no longer available.

Comment: Neither of those is the case. Submit is not listed as deprecated anywhere. You can check all deprecated functions here: http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/

Comment: that's true, but PhpStorm tells me it is.

Comment: When running `jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js` I get a console message: `"jQuery.fn.submit() event shorthand is deprecated"`  when calling `$('form').submit( function(e) { ... })` But yeah, it's not listed in the docs.

Comment: 'tis indeed deprecated. Your link points to the submit event and not the submit function:
https://api.jquery.com/submit-shorthand/